# APKtools (APK Studio) Could not decode arsc file

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, apktool

I am tring to decompile an APK with AKP-Studio (it uses Apktool 2.0.0-Beta9) but on every APK I get this error:

```
May 05, 2015 5:38:30 PM brut.androlib.ApkDecoder decode

INFO: Using Apktool 2.0.0-Beta9 on com.****-1.apk

May 05, 2015 5:38:30 PM brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources loadMainPkg

INFO: Loading resource table...

Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode arsc file

at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:54)

at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:604)

at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:74)
```

I checked it on different systems with different versions of windows (64 and 32 bit)

My java version is:  "1.8.0_45"

Please let me know if have any solution for this.

Comment: I know it is now an "answer" but it is a solution: https://code.google.com/p/androguard/ worked great for me everytime.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You must have to download apktoo_2.0.0rc file. then after You can decompile your apk file and will not get arcs file error.

You can download latest file version from [Here](https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads)

Now Rename your "apktool_2.0.0rc4.jar" to "apktool.jar".

Now delete old "apktool.jar" file from your apktool folder.

**UPDATE:**
__

For Windows users, it's located in:

```
C:\Users\yourusername\.apkstudio\vendor
```

__

Now put this new "apktool.jar" file in your apktool folder where old "apktool.jar" was placed.

now same run your cmd commands like `apktool if framework-res.apk`

and next

`apktool d "your appname.apk without quotes"`

and keep smile..

Comment: I have an apk that works fine, then I changed some apache libs that relate to HttpClient and some code to modify headers and now I get this "Could not decode arsc file" ??  Anything else that works?  Seems like these are related to the githug issues:  https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/924  and  https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/964

Comment: also I'm not able to run those commands?  Where is your root to be able to see framework-res.apk?

Answer (score 1):

For me, 2.0.0 versions had same issue, but `2.0.3` solves the problem.

Download newest apktool.jar version at https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads (apktool owner's repository)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with version 2.0.0. I updated to version 2.1.1 and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem
1. Download  framework-res.apk  from https://basketbuild.com/filedl/devs?dev=aniruddhc&dl=aniruddhc/framework-res.apk
2. You can download latest file version apktool from https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads and change name to "apktool.jar".
3. Open folder Framework,delete old file "apktool.jar",later copy new file "apktool.jar" and file framework.res.apk. Later run file Command Prompt and run command "apktool if framework-res.apk".
4. Delete old file "apktool.jar" and copy new file "apktool.jar" in folder APKTool.
5. End, run command apktool d name_apk

Smile !

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest apktool.jar

Download link
https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/apktool_2.2.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

(2021)I had the same problem. For me moving the apktool folder from windows to desktop was the solution :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).