# Citrix: can't wrap apk using MDKToolkit

Tags: java, android, mdm, citrix, apktool

This has been an ongoing issue for some time now, and I've tried way too many things to post, but I'll attempt to be concise while explaining the issue...

I have a client that wraps our ipa and apk file using XenMobile Enterprise 9.0.3, and MDXToolkit 10.2.  The ipa wraps fine, but the apk is getting this log file:

### **Unpacking app: theapkinquestion...**

I: **Using Apktool 2.0.0** on theapkinquestion.apk
I: Loading resource table...
**brut.androlib.AndrolibException: Could not decode arsc file**
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:52)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResPackagesFromApk(AndrolibResources.java:538)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.loadMainPkg(AndrolibResources.java:63)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.getResTable(AndrolibResources.java:55)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.getResTable(Androlib.java:64)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.setTargetSdkVersion(ApkDecoder.java:209)
    at brut.androlib.ApkDecoder.decode(ApkDecoder.java:92)
    **at brut.apktool.Main.cmdDecode(Main.java:165)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:81)**
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedAppUtility.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedAppUtility.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedAppUtility.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.a.u.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrix.MAM.Android.ManagedAppUtility.AppMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected: 0x00000008, got: 0x0000013d
    at brut.util.ExtDataInput.skipCheckShort(ExtDataInput.java:56)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readValue(ARSCDecoder.java:238)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readEntry(ARSCDecoder.java:201)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readConfig(ARSCDecoder.java:189)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readType(ARSCDecoder.java:157)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readPackage(ARSCDecoder.java:114)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.readTable(ARSCDecoder.java:78)
    at brut.androlib.res.decoder.ARSCDecoder.decode(ARSCDecoder.java:47)
    ... 14 more

**Unable to decompile the original app. Aborting the wrapping process.**

We started getting this error after I changed some code related to how we authenticate using NTLM/Windows Authentication.  A previous version of our apk wrapped fine and it used a deprecated apache DefaultHttpClient class, so it wasn't like I changed that much?

The main question I have, since there's a few resources online that I've followed, is how do I update the Apktool to a newer version and make MDXToolkit see that new version?  We aren't account holders and were barely able to find MDXToolkit 10.0.7 legacy, so we are working on getting the newest 10.2 version now.  Here are some links for basic things I've done:

1) [Installing and Configuring the Citrix MDX Toolkit Build 2.2.1 v372 and Wrapping Apps](http://www.robinhobo.com/installing-configuring-citrix-mdx-toolkit-build-2-2-1-v372-wrapping-apps/)

2) [apktool install instructions](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

3) [APKtools (APK Studio) Could not decode arsc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054156/apktools-apk-studio-could-not-decode-arsc-file)

I've successfully decompiled the apk using apktool 2.0.0-RC4, but whenever I try to use the MDXToolkit to create the .mdx file need for Work Home, I get that log error "**Using Apktool 2.0.0**."  I've see screen shots and discussions about this decoding issue all over that say **Using Apktool 2.0.0-RC4** or another version.  I've even unzipped the "**ManagedAppUtility.jar** that I know is where all those class files in the log are located to see if the apktool.jar was in there to update, but it's not.

Anyone out there in Citrix/XenMobile/Android land know what's going on here?  Is there a way to update the Apktool MDXToolkit uses?  The client we're working with is running version 10.2, the current version from Citrix and we're still getting the same log file no matter if it's 10.0.7 or 10.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that work, a co-worker found this link hidden on Citrix's site that had the latest MDXToolkit version 10.2.1.264, and you don't need a paid account!

https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenmobile/product-software/worx-app-sdx.html

You would think it would be here: https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenmobile.html

I was able to create the .mdx file after updating to the new version and changing the PATH in Citrix > MDXToolkit > android-settings.txt (http://www.robinhobo.com/citrix-mdx-toolkit-find-android-sdk/)

Comment: the link is dead now

Comment: @Lakshay if you find a link, post an answer and I'll accept that as the correct answer and upvote

Comment: Does anyone know where is apktool in Citrix? I need to update it as well.